# Merge SELECT result in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/20c96) and I need to make a SELECT statement which returns all the rows in just one, based on an existing FK.

**For example, here's what I have:**

```
--------------------------------
| id | fk | col1 | col2 | col3 |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 1  |  A   | null | null |
| 2  | 1  | null |   B  | null |
| 3  | 1  | null | null |   C  |
--------------------------------
```

**And here's what I need:**

```
---------------------------
| fk | col1 | col2 | col3 |
---------------------------
| 1  |  A   |   B  |   C  |
---------------------------
```

I'm sure there won't be any conflict since these I'll never get these null columns filled altogether. Just one row at a time will get some value.

I know it seems odd, but I really need this output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate the values grouping by fk column.

```
select fk, max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4), max(col5)
from table1
group by fk
```

Comment: close, just need to add group by fk  ... and now nevermind :P